# Why is 情结 used here?

Tags: word-choice

然后该文作者笔锋一转，接着就指出了中国这种民族主义自豪情节的另一个方面.

But then, the author of this article accurately points out another aspect of this Chinese nationalistic pride.

I thought "自豪" alone is good enough, because it says pride, not "pride plot."

Comment: I think 情节 is a misstype of 情结。情节 is not usually used in context like this，but 情结 do。

Comment: @Jacob wrong. See Thomas' answer below.

Comment: @user3306356  wrong.See my comment below.XD

Answer (score 4):

`情节` is a common typo here. It should be [情结](http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E6%83%85%E7%B5%90). It means [complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_%28psychology%29).

In short, `自豪情节` refers to `emotions, memories, perceptions, and wishes in the personal unconscious organized around pride`.

Other common usage of the word `情结` include:

- **恋母情结/恋父情结**

Oedipus complex. The complex that surrounds the child's desire to have a sexual relationship with the parent of the sex that adheres to their sexual orientation (mother or father)

- **处女情结/处男情结**

The complex that surrounds the desire of dating a virgin, i.e. being the one to take his/her virginity.

Comment: That's why I said it is a mistype.  I did not find any evidence that the 情节 also means 'complex' and interchangeable with 情结. What you have explained about 'complex' belongs to 情结。

Comment: The first sentence in your answer sounds confusing. 情节 _does_ translate to "plot"; the original sentence is clearly a typo.

Comment: I know that  情节 is a typo of 情结 but was not 100% certain because I see just as many uses of 情节 in similar context on a google search...Thank you both for clarifying! I've edited the post. And @Jacob, I actually upvoted your comment above because I agree with you.